# PHP function for mysqli connection gives error

Tags: php, mysqli, message, user-defined-functions

Newer to creating php functions and mysql.  I have function to connect to a database db_conect_nm().  This is in file db_fns.php, and contains the user and password to connect to my db.  I created this to have a more secure db connection.  I had it in a directory outside of public_html, and got error `PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'negoti7'@'localhost' (using password: NO) ...`

Looking for solutions, I saw comments which indicated that perhaps this db user did not have permission from root, so I put it in a directory in public_html, same directory as program where it is being called.  I still get the same error.

I have tested the connection without being a function, and it works.  What is wrong, and why is this not working as a function?  I really want to put this somewhere other than in the code directly and make it more secure.

**db_fns.php content**

```
<?php
//Database server
$host= 'localhost';
$nm_name= 'myname_databasename';  //sanitized data
$nm_user= 'myname_dbusername';
$nm_pword= 'password';

// db connect to nm database
function db_connect_nm()
{
   $nm_connect = new mysqli($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name);

   if (!$nm_connect)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to NM database currently');
   else
   return $nm_connect; 
}

?>
```

I call it from nm_functions.php, db_fns.php is included there.

**nm_functions.php**

```
<?php require_once('sanitizedpathto/db_fns.php');

......some code

  $conn_nm = db_connect_nm();
  $result_sub = $conn_nm->query("select * from subscribers where uname='$username'");

  .... more code

?>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: See: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the scope of the variables? Have you tried defining the variables inside the function to test?

Like this:

```
<?php

// db connect to nm database
function db_connect_nm()
{
  //Database server
    $host= 'localhost';
    $nm_name= 'myname_databasename';  //sanitized data
    $nm_user= 'myname_dbusername';
    $nm_pword= 'password';

   $nm_connect = new mysqli($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name);

   if (!$nm_connect)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to NM database currently');
   else
     return $nm_connect; 
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You are :

- first, declaring some variables, outside of any functions
- then, trying to use those variables from inside a function.

Variables declared outside of a function are not, by default, visible from inside that function.

About that, you should read the [**Variable scope**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section of the manual.

Two possible solutions :

- Use the [`global`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword, to import those variables into your function -- making them visible
- Or **define [constants](http://fr.php.net/define), instead of variables** -- which makes sense, for configuration values.

In the first case, your function would look like this :

```
// db connect to nm database
function db_connect_nm()
{
   // Make these outside variables visible from inside the function
   global $host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name; 

   $nm_connect = new mysqli($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name);

   if (!$nm_connect)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to NM database currently');
   else
   return $nm_connect; 
}
```

And, in the second case, you'd first `define` the constants :

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_DBNAME', 'myname_databasename');
define('DB_USER', 'myname_dbusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
```

And, then, use those constants :

```
// db connect to nm database
function db_connect_nm()
{
   $nm_connect = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DBNAME);

   if (!$nm_connect)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to NM database currently');
   else
   return $nm_connect; 
}
```

This second solution is probably *more clean* than the first one ;-)

Comment: Yes, thanks so much.  I realise the mistake now.  I think the 'define' method would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection variables are not scoped inside the connection function.  You either need to pass them as parameters to the function (preferable) or use the `global` keyword inside to reference them:

```
function db_connect_nm($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name)
{
  $nm_connect = new mysqli($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name);

  //etc...
}
```

Alternate, not preferred:

```
function db_connect_nm()
{
  global $host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name;
  $nm_connect = new mysqli($host, $nm_user, $nm_pword, $nm_name);

  //etc...
}
```